# Server-side checking of a point's existence inside a polygonal area using Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, sql-server, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The logic is: user is editing an existing polygonal area of which extreme points are stored in the database. After editing the modified co-ordinates are updated in the database. Now I need to find whether a certain point exists inside the modified polygon or not. For that I'm assuming I have to do the server-side checking. The client-side checking is easily done by javaScript and that I've done already. The real problem I'm having is to check this on the server-side. Any suggestions?

Comment: What database are you using? With PostgreSQL/PostGIS it's easy. By the way, none of the tags you're using is relevant to a server side calculation.

Comment: I'm using microsoft sql server 2008 R2.

Comment: In that case I cannot help you. Sorry. I gave up on Microsoft many years ago. Nowadays I use only Open Source products.

Comment: If I'm to use the database you've mentioned above, then what would be the procedure? Because I don't know PostgreSQL/PostGIS a bit. Would you please explain in detail?

Comment: Spatial databases, like  PostgreSQL/PostGIS, have functions you can use directly in a query, such as ST_CONTAINS, documented here: http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html - I don't know if MSSQL server 2008 is spatially enabled.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 supports the geometry and geography data types for storing spatial data. These types support methods and properties that allow for the creation, comparison, analysis, and retrieval of spatial data...this is what I got from **msdn**

Comment: Very good! I still don't know SQL Server 2008. Sorry.

Comment: When it's not possible to do this with a query, you'll find here some method's to do it, should be possible to translate them to any other language: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Dr.Molle , again.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented server side point in polygon in PHP.

```
<?php
//Point-In-Polygon Algorithm test parameters
$polySides  = 4; //how many corners the polygon has
$polyX    =  array(4,9,11,2);//horizontal coordinates of corners
$polyY    =  array(10,7,2,2);//vertical coordinates of corners
$x = 3.5;//point
//$y = 13.5;//Outside
$y = 3.5;//Inside

function pointInPolygon($polySides,$polyX,$polyY,$x,$y) {
  $j = $polySides-1 ;
  $oddNodes = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i<$polySides; $i++) {
    if ($polyY[$i]<$y && $polyY[$j]>=$y 
 ||  $polyY[$j]<$y && $polyY[$i]>=$y) {
    if ($polyX[$i]+($y-$polyY[$i])/($polyY[$j]-$polyY[$i])*($polyX[$j]-$polyX[$i])<$x)    {
    $oddNodes=!$oddNodes; }}
   $j=$i; }

  return $oddNodes; }

//Test 
 if (pointInPolygon($polySides,$polyX,$polyY,$x,$y)){
  echo "Is in polygon!";
}
else echo "Is not in polygon";
?>
```

This can be modified to suit language of choice ie. C#

Comment: Thanks. Is this working on GMap? Is this going to work on Gmap? I am asking because my query was how to do the server-side checking. In your approach you have just provided the co-ordinates in the code itself..and that is only implementing client-side approach. I may be wrong. But this is what I thought seeing your approach. Correct me if I am. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Normally point in polygon is easily found with client side using javascript. To do this server side send the point coordinates,`$x&$y`, using Ajax.`$polyX&$polyY` are from database. `for ($i=0; $i<$polySides; $i++) {` will need to be changed suit eg for php PDO `while($row = $stm->fetch())`

Comment: Glad to help.Do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: The code is good for integer values. Whether it is good for float and double values. Already the code is having problem with on the line of the polygon. Please refer the article.https://alienryderflex.com/polygon/

Comment: The code works for both integer and floats,integers were used for illustration only. The problem you refer to is in drawing the polygon not implementing code.If you read the article and see if a point is within the misshapen polygon the logic still holds.